# Excel: Combine multiple (16) columns of data to form unique combinations

Tags: excel, vba, combinations, permutation

First time here, thank you all in advance!
I have minimal VBA experience but believe the solution likely requires it.

The question:
I have 16 columns of data, each 8 rows long:

Columns A,C,E,G,I,K,M,O: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

Columns B,D,F,H,J,L,N,P: A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H

My goal is to make a column of strings with one value from each of the 16 columns without duplicating a number or letter.  The string would maintain a number-letter-number-letter- etc order.

For example:

Accepted results would be: A1B2C3D4E5F6G7H8, A1B2C3D4E5F6**G8H7**

Duplicate letters or numbers would NOT be included: **A**1B2C3D4E5F6G7**A**8, A**1**B**1**C3D4E5F6G7H8

Is this something that is programmable via VBA?  Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. It definitely is programmable.

Answer (score 0):

In `rows` varable you specify how many rows you have and in variable `cols` you specify how many columns you have (since you told that you have 16 columns, I advise you to leave it as it is).

```
Sub t()
Dim rows As Integer, cols As Integer
Dim str, strToAppend As String: str = ""

rows = 1
cols = 16

For i = 1 To rows
    For j = 2 To cols Step 2
        strToAppend = Cells(i, j).Value
        If InStr(str, strToAppend) = 0 Then
            str = str & strToAppend
        End If

        strToAppend = Cells(i, j - 1).Value
        If InStr(str, strToAppend) = 0 Then
            str = str & strToAppend
        End If
    Next j
    Cells(i, cols + 1).Value = str
    str = ""
Next i

End Sub
```